# How do I get the requirements in a module's composer.json merged into the consolidated composer.json?

Tags: 7, composer

I am trying to use *composer* correctly to install a library named `nikic/php-parser`.

Thanks to helpful comments by *Clive*, I now understand that when a Drupal 7 module comes with a `composer.json` file, that file is supposed to be merged into a consolidated `composer.json`-file, and from then on things will be taken care of more or less automatically.

That things are *supposed* to work that way also follows from this note on the **Composer Manager** project page:

> Composer Manager allows each contributed module to ship with its own
>   composer.json file, listing the module-specific requirements. **It then
>   merges the requirements of all found modules into the consolidated
>   composer.json file.** This results in a single vendor/ directory shared
>   across all modules which prevents code duplication and version
>   mismatches. [My emphasis.]

The Drupal site where I use for testing is a fresh install of Drupal 7, organized as Drupal 7 is normally organized when you install it using drush (`drush si standard`).

The **Composer Manager** package contains a `composer.json` with the following requirement:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "nikic/php-parser": "^4.2"
}
```

I have the Drupal variable `composer_manager_vendor_dir` set to `sites/all/vendor` and the composer directory for the consolidated `composer.json` is set to  `/sites/default/files/composer`.

The consolidated `composer.json` currently contains:

```
{
  "require": {
    "symfony/yaml": ">=3.1",
    "php": ">=5.3.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "autoloader-suffix": "ComposerManager",
    "vendor-dir": "../../../all/vendor"
  },
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I.e., it does *not* include a requirement for `nikic/php-parser`. The note from the project cited above seems to imply that it would somehow be merged in automatically.  This is yet to happen on my test site.

Following up another hint by *Clive*, I ran:

```
drush composer-manager install
```

This resulted in:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v3.1.0)
    Downloading: 100%         
Generating autoload files
```

I.e. it did the updates that was required per the consolidated `composer.json`. But it did not pay attention to the `composer.json` in the module's directory.

Trying:

```
drush composer-manager update
```

... did not resolve the issue.

There must be something fairly obvious I am missing.

How do I get the requirements in a module's composer.json merged into the consolidated composer.json (apart from splicing it in "by hand")?

Comment: Have you read the module page? Not having a go, it’s just the “How does it work?” section seems to explain quite well where you’ve gone wrong, or more to the point what that module is able to do for you, and how you interact with it (via a module’s composer.json file rather than the command line). If you want to use composer in the command line, I expect you need to use it as normal, it won’t know anything about how your drupal site is organised

Comment: And by that I mean `cd /path/to/composer/root; composer require ...`

Comment: Sorry, I meant the composer root in your site, not the path to the executable (I think that’s somewhere in sites/default/files by default, but it’s been a long time since I used the module). The automated bit is that it will scan all module folders for a composer.json, merge all the required libraries it finds into one big composer.json file, then download everything as “normal”. I was never under the impression that it was supposed to be used via the command line, just via custom composer.json files in modules. You probably _can_ use it via the command line, composer is flexible, but like...

Comment: ...I say, I’m not under the impression the module was designed to enable that workflow, so you may have to implement something custom for this. Apologies if I have that wrong, I’m on mobile and going off memory a bit

Comment: Oh wait, does `drush composer-manager install` do anything? That just crept into my brain, seems familiar

Comment: FWIW this module was totally problematic for me. I just use Composer as normal with Drupal 7 without it. Just tell Drupal where the autoloader file is (for vendor classes) so it’s bootstrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.

This is supposed to happen automatically. If the module is enabled with *drush* under Drupal 7, it does.  If you use *other* means to enable, the module, this might not happen.

In case the root `composer.json` for some reason is missing 
the requirements for a specific module, using *drush* to disable and then again *re-enable* the module fixes the problem.  E.g.:

```
drush dis composer_manager -y
drush en composer_manager -y
```

This seems to be all that is required.

It should be emphasised that this is only valid for Drupal 7. Drupal 8 is a completely different beast.